# What is the emblem on this ring?

Tags: identification, archaeology

After cleaning up a local cave, among lots of trash this ring was found laying underneath.

Can anyone identify this emblem?

Location: Center, Israel

[image]
[image]

Comment: Any idea for a time frame for the trash?

Comment: @mary recent 10's years, mostly trash people left inside.

Comment: looks like a bull's head or two daggers